# One-liner to create multiple strings from single loop in python

Tags: python, string

Using list comprehension I can create something simple like this

```
['X{}'.format(x) for x in range(2)]
```

which produces `['X0', 'X1']`. But I want to create separate and multiple output strings, preferably from the same list comprehension statement.

I want my output to be `['X0','Y0','Z0','X1','Y1' 'Z1']` naturally something like `['X{},Y{},Z{}'.format(x,x,x) for x in range(2)]`, doesn't quite cut the mustard.

Any ideas of how to do this in one line?

EDIT: It is not paramount that it is on one line, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a *nested comprehension*:

```
r = ['{}{}'.format(ch, x) for x in range(2) for ch in 'XYZ']
print(r)
# ['X0', 'Y0', 'Z0', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Double list comprehension

```
reduce([ letter+str(number) for letter in 'ABC' for number in range(x)], [])
```

Answer (score 1):

And one more way to go (still a one-liner):

```
sum([['X{}'.format(x),'Y{}'.format(x),'Z{}'.format(x)] for x in range(2)],[])
# ['X0', 'Y0', 'Z0', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from `itertools`

```
In [59]: ["{}{}".format(char,i) for i,char in itertools.product(range(2), "XYZ")]
Out[59]: ['X0', 'Y0', 'Z0', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List = ['{}{}'.format(Letter, Num) for Num in range(2) for Letter in 'XYZ']
print(List)
```